# How to read binary data from Buffer node.js as number?

Tags: node.js, buffer

Currently I am receiving a message with my udp server it arrives as [`<Buffer 43 31 07 55 56>`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) this is supposed to be an ID `4331075556`

- `obj.toString()` returns `C1UV`
- `parseInt(obj)` returns `NaN`
- `JSON.stringify(obj)` returns `[67,49,7,85,86]`

How can I convert `<Buffer 43 31 07 55 56>` to `4331075556`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to specify an additional argument in toString():

```
obj.toString('hex')
```

Comment: Awesome, missed the encoding list, tried `binary` & `ascii`  mentioned in another doc. I didn't think of the values as being hex.